# How can I remove all lists from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What is the most pythonic way to remove all lists in a list?

For example, if there is a list like this `[1,2,['randompie'],3,[],4,5]`, how can I make it like this `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Here is what I've tried:

```
[elem for elem in [1,2,['randompie'],3,[],4,5] if type(elem)!='list']
```

Comment: Try

list2 = [x for x in list1 if x is not list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to easily filter all non-list elements from your list:

```
>>> l = [1,2,['randompie'],3,[],4,5]
>>> [el for el in l if not isinstance(el, list)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note I used `isinstance` rather than `type`. This is for two reasons. The former function is preferred because [it takes parent classes into account](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). And because `isinstance` allows you to easily extend the list comprehension to filter out other types such as `tuple`s or `dict`s:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, ['randompie'], 3, [], 4, 5, (1,)]
>>> [el for el in l if not isinstance(el, (list, tuple))] # filter out tuples and list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use list comprehension:

```
your_list = [1,2,['randompie'],3,[],4,5]
your_list = [thing for thing in your_list if type(thing) is not list]
```

Comment: Please avoid answering questions where the OP has no demonstrated that they've made an effort at solving their own problem. Such questions are to broad and should be closed as such.